# I want to calculate the pH of a solution when the concentration of H+ has been previously calculated

Tags: python

The concentration of H+ is equal to 0.0000001. I want to solve the following equation:

```
pH = -log(H+)
```

How can I write it in python? I have taken the last calculated value of H+ in order to calculate the pH.

I tried the following:

```
x = H[-1].real
print(x)

pH = -math.log(x)
print(pH)
```

But the results is false. What do I do wrong?

Comment: "*The concentration of H+ is equal to 0.0000001*" what is the unit? How are your results incorrect? You should show what you got and what you expect

Comment: What is `H` in the Python code (seems to be a list or tuple, what are the items?)?

Comment: the unit is mol/L. The pH should be 7. but python results in pH=14

Comment: Notice that `math.log` will give you the natural logarithm, often written as "ln" i mathematical texts. You want the base-10 logarithm, `math.log10`.

Comment: I have calculated the H for different times, so I have put in an array. And then I took only the final value (H[-1]).

Comment: `math.log(0.0000001, 10)` or `math.log10(0.0000001)`

Comment: `-math.log10(0.0000001)` -> `7` as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

x = 0.0000001357                   # measured value
floatDigits = '.8f'                # rounding to 8 digits 

H = float(format(x, floatDigits))  # converting to float

print(H)

pH = -math.log10(H)          # calculating the negative of log base 10
print(pH)
```

results:

H = 1.4e-07

pH = 6.853871964321762